# Updating values of custom object using Input field

Tags: visualforce

I have a VF page and controller which shows a list of Sales persons and their Goals against them in an Input field. When the goals in input field are changed and the "Save" button is pressed, it should update the goal for that OSR in the custom object. The code gives no error, but the values are not updating.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="UpdateValues">
<apex:form >
         <apex:outputLabel value="Region" />
    <apex:selectList value="{!regn}" size="1" id="Region">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Valuesr}" />
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="districtSelect"/>
    </apex:SelectList>

    <apex:outputPanel id="districtSelect">
    <apex:outputLabel value="District"/>
    <apex:selectList value="{!dist}" size="1" id="dist">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Values}"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="Inputs"/>
    </apex:selectList>
    </apex:outputPanel>

  <apex:pageblock >
   <apex:pageblockTable value="{!Sales_Rep}" var="rep" id="Inputs">
        <apex:column headerValue="Sales Rep" value="{!rep.Sales_Rep__c}">
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Revised_Goal">
            <apex:inputField value="{!rep.Rental_Revenue_Goal__c}"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
        </apex:column>            
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here is Controller:

```
public with sharing class UpdateValues {

public PageReference save() {
update Sales_Rep;
return null;
}

public string regn {get; set;}
public string dist {get; set;}    

public list <SelectOption> getValuesr()
{
list <selectoption> lsreg = new List<selectoption> ();
lsreg.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
Set<String> regionSet = new Set<String>();
for (User_Stats__C Rgn : [SELECT Region__c FROM User_Stats__C where Region__c != null and Region__c != 0 and Region__c != 1 and District__c != null and District__c != '0'])
{
    String region = string.valueOf(Rgn.Region__c);
    if(!regionSet.contains(region)) lsreg.add(new selectoption(region, region));
    regionSet.add(region);
}
return lsreg;
}

public list <SelectOption> getValues()

{
list <selectoption> ls = new List<selectoption> ();
ls.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
Set<String> distSet = new Set<String>();
for (User_Stats__C dist : [SELECT District__c FROM User_Stats__c where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c != null and Region__c != null and Region__c != 1 and Region__c != 0])
{
    if(!distSet.contains(dist.District__c)) ls.add(new selectoption(dist.District__c, dist.District__c));
    distSet.add(dist.District__c);
}
return ls;
}

public List<User_Stats__c> Sales_Rep{
    get{
            Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
            Sales_rep=[Select Id, Sales_Rep__c, Rental_Revenue_Goal__c From User_Stats__c where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Sales_Rep__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null];
        return Sales_Rep;
        }
    set;
    }
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue might be caused by the fact that in the save method you are calling to update **Sales_Rep**, effectively referencing the getter of the **public List < User_Stats__c > Sales_Rep** field, which always return list of Sales_rep fetched from the server.

This is your code slightly re-written might help you understand what went wrong:

```
public with sharing class UpdateValues {

    public PageReference save() {
        update getSales_Rep();
        return null;
    }

    public string regn {get; set;}
    public string dist {get; set;}    

    ...

    public List<User_Stats__c> getSales_Rep(){
        Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
        Sales_rep=[Select Id, Sales_Rep__c, Rental_Revenue_Goal__c From User_Stats__c where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Sales_Rep__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null];
        return Sales_Rep;
    }
}
```

I would advise to make **Sales_Rep** a regular field, without default getter, but in turn populate the field in the controller's constructor, like so:

```
public with sharing class UpdateValues {

    public List<User_Stats__c> Sales_Rep { get; set; }

    public UpdateValues() {
        Sales_Rep = getSalesReps();
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        update Sales_Rep;
        return null;
    }

    public string regn {get; set;}
    public string dist {get; set;}    

    public list <SelectOption> getValuesr() {
        list <selectoption> lsreg = new List<selectoption> ();
        lsreg.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
        Set<String> regionSet = new Set<String>();
        for (User_Stats__C Rgn : [SELECT Region__c FROM User_Stats__C where Region__c != null and Region__c != 0 and Region__c != 1 and District__c != null and District__c != '0'])
        {
            String region = string.valueOf(Rgn.Region__c);
            if(!regionSet.contains(region)) lsreg.add(new selectoption(region, region));
            regionSet.add(region);
        }
        return lsreg;
    }

    public list <SelectOption> getValues() {
        list <selectoption> ls = new List<selectoption> ();
        ls.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
        Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
        Set<String> distSet = new Set<String>();
        for (User_Stats__C dist : [SELECT District__c FROM User_Stats__c where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c != null and Region__c != null and Region__c != 1 and Region__c != 0])
        {
            if(!distSet.contains(dist.District__c)) ls.add(new selectoption(dist.District__c, dist.District__c));
            distSet.add(dist.District__c);
        }
        return ls;
    }

    public List<User_Stats__c> getSalesReps{
        Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
        Sales_rep=[Select Id, Sales_Rep__c, Rental_Revenue_Goal__c From User_Stats__c where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Sales_Rep__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null];
        return Sales_Rep;
    }
}
```